# Add an if/else window width clause to a Wordpress navwalker.php

Tags: javascript, php, wp-nav-walker

The goal here is to make a Wordpress boostrap main menu top level item which has sub-items act as a clickable link for devices > 768 px wide and retain the default behavior for small device.

There is the following code in the navwalker.php file around line 83:

```
// If item has_children add atts to a.
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
    $atts['href'] = '#';
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-toggle';
}
```

To make the link clickable for normal screens I need to modify the code but then add an else statement so that it retains the default behavior, something like:

```
// If item has_children add atts to a.
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) { 
    if ( $windowwidth < 768) {
        $atts['href'] = '#';
        $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
        $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-toggle';
    } else {
        $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : ''; 
        //$atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
        $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-toggle';
    }       
}
```

The question is how to obtain the $windowwidth, presumably in JavaScript, so that I can use it in a PHP if/else clause.

Comment: Why not just do it all client side?

Comment: This is a job for the front end.  You should handle this completely with CSS and media queries. Some javascript where necessary, but it's not the job of PHP.

Comment: Thank you, however the goal was not to recreate the wordpress bootstrap menu and/or css. Anyway, I kept researching and found an off-the-shelf solution at https://colorlib.com/wp/forums/topic/clickable-parent-menu-disable-on-desktops/. If you scroll to the Sept 15, 2015 entry by Movin, he has included/written a WP plugin which I tested and works.